# alternate way of managing deletion of jackrabbit workspace

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I am working on jackrabbit work space deletion but find that jackrabbit does not support work space deletion is there any alternate in jackrabbit for deletion of work space (like disable work space programmatically)

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/frequently-asked-questions.html#How_do_I_delete_a_workspace_in_Jackrabbit, it looks like you just delete the directory when the repository instance is not running.